# Setting the adapter on a Listview in a custom view injected with Butterknife

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, butterknife

I have an Activity with a custom view in its Xml layout file:

```
<com.example.androidmontreal.mvp.infrastructure.views.AndroidRaceResultsView
    android:id="@+id/raceResults"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    ...
```

In the onCreate method of this activity I use Butterknife to inject my views:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mvp_main);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    ...

}
```

In my custom view I have a listview. Before adding Butterknife I used to set the adapter for the listview in the `onFinishInflate` method:

```
    @Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    ...

    listView.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
}
```

Since adding Butterknife however, I get an NPE on the line where I set the adapter, because at that stage listview is Null.

My understanding is that the view is only instantiated when the `Butterknife.inject()` method in the Activity is called, but this happens after the view has been inflated.  What I can't figure out is when I should set the adapter for the listView.

**Edit:** It seems that the children views on my custom view is null, even after `utterknife.inject()` has been called on the activity. If I add a call to `Butterknife.inject` to my `onFinishInflate` method however, I get an error saying that `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view with id '2131034112' for field 'listView' was not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just after

> ButterKnife.inject(this);

Internally it fills the listView variable, so it's become available for you.

Ensure that you have

```
@InjectView(R.id.raceResults)
AndroidRaceResultsView listView;
```

in you activity.

Comment: The inject call is on my Activity, which does not have access to the listView field on my custom view.  Adding an Inject call to my custom view introduces a new error (See edit in the question)

Comment: ok, then you'll better take a look at https://github.com/mmBs/NavigationDrawerSI/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mmbialas/pl/navigationdrawersi/ui/navigationdrawer/NavigationDrawerView.java

Comment: You should check that you have injected your custom view into activity, as in previous link, take a look at how 
    NavigationDrawerView is comming available in MainActivity

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because the code you linked solved it for me.   I changed my main xml layout to use `<include ... />` with the layout attribute specified as the layout file of my custom control instead of having `<com.example.androidmontreal.mvp.infrastructure.views.AndroidRaceResultsView ../>`   I don't understand why this works, but it does.